# How to convert IPictureDisp to System.Drawing.Image

Tags: c#, interop

From a COM library (Microsoft Office Document Imaging aka MODI) I receive an image as an IPictureDisp which I would like to convert to a System.Drawing.Image object.

What would be the best way to do that?

Currently I'm using the code below, which however throws an NotImplementedException.

```
internal sealed class IPictureDispHost : AxHost
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Default Constructor, required by the framework.
    /// </summary>
    private IPictureDispHost() : base(string.Empty) { }
    /// <summary>
    /// Convert the image to an ipicturedisp.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="image">The image instance</param>
    /// <returns>The picture dispatch object.</returns>
    public new static object GetIPictureDispFromPicture(Image image)
    {
        return AxHost.GetIPictureDispFromPicture(image);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Convert the dispatch interface into an image object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="picture">The picture interface</param>
    /// <returns>An image instance.</returns>
    public new static Image GetPictureFromIPicture(object picture)
    {
        return AxHost.GetPictureFromIPicture(picture);
    }
}

...

// somewhere later the conversion gets called
Image image = IPictureDispHost.GetPictureFromIPicture(picture);
```

This is the exception stack trace:

```
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IPicture.GetHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetPictureFromIPicture(Object picture)
   at DocumentViewer.IPictureDispHost.GetPictureFromIPicture(Object picture)
```

I have references to stdole, System.Windows.Forms and System.Drawing in my project.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems the picture obtained from the Microsoft Office Document Imaging COM components is not a valid IPictureDisp object and there seems no way to convert it.

Comment: the more recent answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/56564390/9792594 works for me

Answer (score 5):

Check out this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/andreww/archive/2007/07/30/converting-between-ipicturedisp-and-system-drawing-image.aspx).

It describes three different options to take, just pick the one you find easiest or "cleanest" for your purposes (including the one you claim not to be working for you).

---

Olivier Jacot-Descombes: The link above is broken. I've added the corresponding link from the Internet Archive [WayBackMachine](https://web.archive.org):

[Converting between IPictureDisp and System.Drawing.Image](https://web.archive.org/web/20160114043055/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2007/07/30/converting-between-ipicturedisp-and-system-drawing-image.aspx) (MSDN Blogs > Andrew Whitechapel).

Comment: Thanks, that's a great article. My sample code above was actually taken from that site.

Answer (score 2):

```
Function GetImage(MyIPicture As stdole.IPictureDisp) As Drawing.Image
    If CType(MyIPicture.Type, Integer) <> 1 then Throw New ArgumentException("Image not supported")
    Return Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(MyIPicture.Handle, MyIPicture.hPal)
End Function
```

Inspired from [this post in the MSDN Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/db1100b7-faca-4361-822c-b05f08cfe3f5/use-of-icons-out-of-ribbons?forum=vsto).
No idea why the `CType(MyIPicture.Type, Integer) = 1` is required, but it works..

Comment: This works, and probably should be the accepted answer, thanks.

Comment: IPicture.Type = 1 is bitmap, and FromHBitmap() requires a handle to a bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
picture1.image = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.Support.IPictureDispToImage(pict)
```

Comment: IPictureDispToImage() should be in the Support namespace? However, I get the same NotImplementedException.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.Support.IPictureDispToImage is not guaranteed to always be included in future updates. So... taking the example from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555417 I came up with the following

Example

**Public Class ImageToPictureDispConverter**

```
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.AxHost

Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New("{63109182-966B-4e3c-A8B2-8BC4A88D221C}")
End Sub

Public Function GetImageFromIPictureDisp(ByVal objImage As stdole.IPictureDisp) As System.Drawing.Image
    Dim objPicture As System.Drawing.Image
    objPicture = CType(MyBase.GetPictureFromIPicture(objImage), System.Drawing.Image)

    Return objPicture
End Function
```

**End Class**

I see in your constructor that you pass an empty string. I ended up having to pass the following string "{63109182-966B-4e3c-A8B2-8BC4A88D221C}". If I passed an empty string I received a system.formatexception error. It looks like you have everything I have except for this string in your call to base.

Hope this helps.