# Delphi Wacom SDK

Tags: delphi, sdk, wacom

recently my company bought a Wacom STU-530 signature pad and I've to realize a prgram that acquire the client signature from it and create a pdf with the signature.
I use FastReport for realizing the PDF, but I need to acquire the signature from the wacom tablet.
With the sdk I realized this code:

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnFirmaClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  objFirma: SigObj;
  ctlFirma: TSigCtl;
  picFirma: TPicture;
  res: CaptureResult;
begin
  picFirma := TPicture.Create;
  ctlFirma := TSigCtl.Create(Self);
  res := ctlFirma.Capture('Firmare per accettazione',
    'Formazione del personale in affiancamento');
  case res of
    CaptureOK: begin
      objFirma := SigObj(ctlFirma.Signature);
      SetOlePicture(picFirma, objFirma.Picture(300, 300, 'image/bmp', 0.5, $000000,
        $ffffff, -1.0, -1.0, RenderOutputPicture or RenderColor32BPP or
        RenderEncodeData));
      picFirma.SaveToFile('firma.bmp');
    end;
  end;
  ctlFirma.Free;
  picFirma.Free;
end;
```

The SigObj has a method that return a IPictureDisp and I need to convert it into a TImage so I've used the SetOlePicture, but When I save the Image it is unreadable. If I try to save the picture with

```
picFirma.bitmap.SaveToFile('firma.bmp')
```

the resulting bitmap is void.
What is wrong in my code?

Comment: I think you need to ask the vendor about this. They should provide you an example of how to accomplish what you want.

Comment: The problem is not the Wacom SDK, but the IPictureDisp it return. The SetOlePicture Should connect the IPictureDisp object to the TPicture object, but when I save the image on a file it is unreadable or empty.

Comment: @Eros RBK may be right; Indeed, not all libraries do the correct iPictureDisp implementation, even Microsoft themselves do not implement it correctly - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/480350/976391  Ask the vendor, try to get sample code from them

Comment: MSDN about IPictureDisp  says two interesting things: 1) it has `Type` property of PICTYPE type which can be `bitmap` or anything else including `non-initialized` type-stub : https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms687195.aspx  and 2) typically objects with IPictureDisp interface also do implement IPicture interface that has a native `SaveToFile` method https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms694504.aspx

Comment: if your Delphi still comes with sources for Vcl.AxCtrls unit try to step into and to debug internals of `SetOlePicture` and that might hint you which assumption went wrong

Answer (score 0):

According to Signature Components API delivered with Signature SDK to get the signature in bitmap you should use RenderBitmap method.

> *RenderBitmap( outputFilename, dimensionX, dimensionY, mimeType, inkWidth, nkColor, backgroundColor, paddingX, paddingY, flags)*
>   Renders an image of the signature, creating an image file or returning
>   the binary data. Optionally encodes the SigObj data in the generated
>   image using steganographic techniques.

```
    objFirma:= SigObj(ctlFirma.Signature);
    objFirma.RenderBitmap('firma.bmp', 300, 300, 'image/bmp', 0.5, $000000,
    $ffffff, -1.0, -1.0, RenderOutputFilename or RenderColor32BPP or RenderEncodeData);
```

Comment: Some informative text would be nice, since code only answers often gets downvoted.

Comment: Thank you kind sir for your suggestion. Answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of Wacom signature SDK 4.5.6 your code works fine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).