# Using office icons as image on command button within userform

Tags: vba, outlook, user-controls, icons, commandbutton

I'm creating some userforms for use within OutLook (2010). I'd like to utilize some of the office icons as images on the various command buttons. Is there anyway I can refer to office icons in such a way as to avoid having to distribute the *.ico file(s) with the macro?

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is. This will get you the blue Info circle:

```
Sub UserForm_Activate()
 Set CommandButton1.Picture = Application.CommandBars.GetImageMso("Info", 20, 20)
End Sub
```

You will have to assign it when loading the userform (`UserForm_Activate` or `UserForm_Initialize`).
I just discovered this myself, but I think it's a good start.

Comment: Nice. A combination of your answer and this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/56564390/9792594 worked for me