# Using Built-in Icons Programmatically

Tags: vba, ms-access

This is a question that seems so simple that I can't find an answer to it anywhere online.  I want to set a Tab Control page tab picture property to a built-in icon programmatically.  I can do it manually easily enough in property sheet but accessing the built-in icons programmatically has be stumped.

I am looking for what I need to add to the end of this line to get the "Go To Next" icon:

```
Me.Page2.Picture = ???
```

Like I said, simple - but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere... Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using office icons as image on command button within userform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42841507/using-office-icons-as-image-on-command-button-within-userform) (it says "for command button" but the picture property works the same way on other controls)