# How do I convert stdole.stdPicture to a .net image in C#?

Tags: c#, image, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

Im building an Add-In for Outlook where I copy all exchange users from the global address list to the local contacts.

The problem is I want transfer the picture of the exchange user too, but `exchUser.GetPicture()` returns a stdole.stdPicture and I have not yet found a working solution to download or convert it into an image/jpg/...

Here the code to get the exchange User from the global address list:

```
private void EnumerateGAL()
{
    Outlook.AddressList gal = Application.Session.GetGlobalAddressList(); 
    if (gal != null) 
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= gal.AddressEntries.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            Outlook.AddressEntry addrEntry = gal.AddressEntries[i];
            Outlook.ExchangeUser exchUser = addrEntry.GetExchangeUser();
                    
            if (addrEntry.AddressEntryUserType == Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry
                && exchUser.CompanyName == "")
            {
                CreateContact(exchUser);
                //exchUser.GetPicture() returns stdole.stdPicture
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

The closest solution I found, was a conversion of stdole.IPictureDisp which returns a bitmap but IPuctureDisp and stdPicture isn´t the same as I read somewhere.

```
public static System.Drawing.Image ConvertPicture(stdole.IPictureDisp image)
{
    int type = image.Type;
    if (type == 1)
    {
        IntPtr hPal = (IntPtr)image.hPal;
        return Image.FromHbitmap((IntPtr)image.Handle, hPal);
    }
    return null;
}
```

In the end I need to download the picture because I can only upload a picture to a contact with a path.
So, is there a way to download a stdPicture or convert it to be able to download it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert IPictureDisp to System.Drawing.Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468972/how-to-convert-ipicturedisp-to-system-drawing-image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are four main ways to get the job done.

The "traditional" approach is to use the `GetIPictureDispFromPicture` and `GetPictureFromIPicture` methods in the `System.Windows.Forms.AxHost` class. These are both protected members of the class, so you can't use them externally. For this reason, it is common to subclass the `AxHost` class and expose public methods that internally call the base class protected methods. This approach allows you to convert in both directions:

```
internal class AxHostConverter : AxHost
{
    private AxHostConverter() : base("") { }

    static public stdole.IPictureDisp ImageToPictureDisp(Image image)
    {
       return (stdole.IPictureDisp)GetIPictureDispFromPicture(image);
    }

    static public Image PictureDispToImage(stdole.IPictureDisp pictureDisp)
    {
        return GetPictureFromIPicture(pictureDisp);
    }
}
```

Your second option is to use `OleLoadPicture` or `OleCreatePictureIndirect`. There's an old support article on the topic here. `OleLoadPicture` creates a new picture object and initializes it from the contents of a stream.

```
internal class OleCreateConverter

{

    [DllImport("oleaut32.dll", EntryPoint = "OleCreatePictureIndirect",

        CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, PreserveSig = true)]

    private static extern int OleCreatePictureIndirect(

        [In] PictDescBitmap pictdesc, ref Guid iid, bool fOwn,

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out object ppVoid);

    const short _PictureTypeBitmap = 1;
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal class PictDescBitmap
    {
        internal int cbSizeOfStruct = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PictDescBitmap));
        internal int pictureType = _PictureTypeBitmap;
        internal IntPtr hBitmap = IntPtr.Zero;
        internal IntPtr hPalette = IntPtr.Zero;
        internal int unused = 0;

        internal PictDescBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            this.hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap();
        }
    }

    public static stdole.IPictureDisp ImageToPictureDisp(Image image)
    {
       if (image == null || !(image is Bitmap))
        {
            return null;
        }

        PictDescBitmap pictDescBitmap = new PictDescBitmap((Bitmap)image);
        object ppVoid = null;
        Guid iPictureDispGuid = typeof(stdole.IPictureDisp).GUID;
        OleCreatePictureIndirect(pictDescBitmap, ref iPictureDispGuid, true, out ppVoid);
        stdole.IPictureDisp picture = (stdole.IPictureDisp)ppVoid;
        return picture;
    }

    public static Image PictureDispToImage(stdole.IPictureDisp pictureDisp)
    {
        Image image = null;
        if (pictureDisp != null && pictureDisp.Type == _PictureTypeBitmap)
        {
            IntPtr paletteHandle = new IntPtr(pictureDisp.hPal);
            IntPtr bitmapHandle = new IntPtr(pictureDisp.Handle);
            image = Image.FromHbitmap(bitmapHandle, paletteHandle);
        }
        return image;
    }
}
```

Your third option is to use the VB6 compatibility library, documented here. To use this, you'll need to add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.dll`, which is listed on the .NET tab of the `Add References` dialog (it resides in the GAC). Then, you can use the `ImageToIPictureDisp` and `IPictureDispToImage` methods in the `Support` class. This is obviously by far the simplest approach, although it does pull in the VB6 compatibility DLL. Internally, the VB6 compatibility code looks a lot like the second option above – using `OleCreatePictureIndirect`.

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6;

internal class VB6CompatibilityConverter
{
    public static stdole.IPictureDisp ImageToPictureDisp(Image image)
    {
        return (stdole.IPictureDisp)Support.ImageToIPictureDisp(image);
    }

    public static Image PictureDispToImage(stdole.IPictureDisp pictureDisp)
    {
        return Support.IPictureDispToImage(pictureDisp);
    }
}
```

Finally, you can implement `IPictureDisp` and `IPicture` yourself. This is fine if you just want to convert from an Image to an `IPictureDisp`, but doesn't help you converting in the other direction. The implementation below relies on the Image actually being a derived Bitmap type, because we call `Bitmap.GetHbitmap` internally. If you want to keep the support to the generic `Image` type, you'll have to do a lot more work to p/invoke to a bunch of undocumented GDI methods instead

```
internal class PictureDispConverter
{
    public static stdole.IPictureDisp BitmapToPictureDisp(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        return new PictureDispImpl(bitmap);
    }
 
    public static Image PictureDispToBitmap(stdole.IPictureDisp pictureDisp)
    {
        // TODO
        return null;
    }
}

internal class PictureDispImpl : stdole.IPictureDisp, stdole.IPicture
{
    #region Init

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static extern void DeleteObject(IntPtr handle);

    private Bitmap _image;
    private IntPtr _handle;
 
    public PictureDispImpl(Bitmap image)
    {
        _image = image;
    }
 
    ~PictureDispImpl()
    {
        if (_handle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            DeleteObject(_handle);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IPictureDisp Members

    public int Width
    {
        get { return _image.Width; }
    }

    public int Height
    {
        get { return _image.Height; }
    }

    public short Type
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }

    public int Handle
    {
        get
        {
            if (_handle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                _handle = _image.GetHbitmap();
            }
            return _handle.ToInt32();
        }
    }
 
    public int hPal
    {
        get { return 0; }
        set { }
    }
 
    public void Render(
        int hdc, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, int xSrc, int ySrc, int cxSrc, int cySrc, IntPtr prcWBounds)
    {
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHdc(new IntPtr(hdc));
        graphics.DrawImage(
            _image, new Rectangle(x, y, cx, cy), xSrc, ySrc, cxSrc, cySrc, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
 
    #endregion

    #region IPicture Members
 
    public int Attributes
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }

    public int CurDC
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }

    public bool KeepOriginalFormat
    {
        get { return false; }
        set { }
    }
 
    public void PictureChanged()
    {
    }
 
    public void SaveAsFile(IntPtr pstm, bool fSaveMemCopy, out int pcbSize)
    {
        pcbSize = 0;
    }

    public void SelectPicture(int hdcIn, out int phdcOut, out int phbmpOut)
    {
        phdcOut = 0;
        phbmpOut = 0;
    }

    public void SetHdc(int hdc)
    {

    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but if I see this right, all of the solutions use IPictureDisp which is not the format I want to convert. I tested it with the "traditional" way and it doesn´t accept stdPicture.

Comment: Okay, I found I just can cast the ```stdPicture``` to ```IPictureDisp```. ```(stdole.IPictureDisp)exchUser.GetPicture()``` and then I can use the methods which use ```IPictureDisp```